# Script to produce an alert only when a nonempty textbox is editted

Tags: javascript

I would like to find and use a script that only produces an alert when a non empty text box is edited. Furthermore, I want the alert to ask whether he user really wants to make the edit and to restore the text, if not. Does such exist or could it be developed in javascript?

Comment: You will need to develop, as it is a very specific behavior.

Comment: It can be developed easily. I'm not going to code for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNAG12/5Sp4d/)

Also try to post what you tried

Comment: I have not tried anything, but I am experimenting with the fiddle material to see if I can make it work for me. It looks promising if I can add it to my gae application. I don't have any external javascript scripts in the app, yet, so I am having to learn to incorporate such.

Comment: Ok. Use Jquery or some other framework. makes your job a lot easier. Specially cross browser nonsense